# Java JTextPane + HTML

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

I am trying to style my messages inside my JTextPane with HTMl/CSS. The JTextPane is setup to understand HTML formating and its working fine to style the messages with CSS (but not all instructions).

For some reason the border property and position:relative are not working..

Here is my code to print to the JTextPane:

```
                // Print the message
                try {
                    kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<div style=\"display:block;background-color:#fafafa;border-bottom:1px solid #000;"
                            + "padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:8px;\">"
                            + "<div style=\"position:relative;width:250px;float:left;color:#b0a9a9;\">Lucy Frank</div>"
                            + "<div style=\"position:relative;float:right;color:#b0a9a9;\">14.10</div>"
                            + "<div>Test message</div>"
                            + "</div>", 0, 0, null);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

14.10 should be displayed on the right next to Lucy Frank, and also there should be a black border just under the div..

Any ideas why its not displaying like its supposed to?

Answer (score 2):

> For some reason the border property and position:relative are not working..

Java HTML rendering supports a subset of HTML **3.2** elements & (more specific to this question) a limited amount of CSS.  Validate the styles using a CSS validation service.  If it is valid & still does not work, you might presume that no, Java's HTML/CSS support does not extend that far.